# Problem about an Inequality

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need a hint to solve this inequality
If $x_i >0$ for all $i$ then
$(x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n}$ $<$ $(x_1+...x_n)\over n$
I tried a little by induction over n, but i dont go anywhere with that

Comment: Check what you wrote: it didn't come up clearly.

Comment: Sorry I don't speak english well, but I think is clear now

Comment: What you want is called "the Means Inequality". You can check it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means . Its proof is easy but a little lengthy, and it uses induction.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Proofs_of_the_AM.E2.80.93GM_inequality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Lemma**: Let $n$ be an integer $>1$ and let $b_1\cdots b_n$ be positive real numbers not all equal such that $b_1\cdots b_n=1$. Then $b_1+\cdots+b_n >n$

Proof: For $n=2$, we have to show that if $b_1\cdot b_2=1$, then $b_1 +b_2>2$. Since $b_1\not= b_2$, so

$$0<(\sqrt{b_1}-\sqrt{b_2})^2=b_1-2\sqrt{b_1 b_2}+b_2=b_1-2+b_2$$

i.e., $b_1+b_2>2$ as desired. Now suppose we have already proven the assertion for $n$, and $b_1\cdots b_n b_{n+1}=1$. Since the $b_j$'s does not have the same value we may suppose $b_1\le b_j \le b_{n+1}$ and $b_1< b_{n+1}$. We claim that $b_1<1<b_{n+1}$ suppose to the contrary that is not the case, so if  $1\le b_1$, then we have $b_1\cdots b_n  b_{n+1}\not=1$ similarly when $b_{n+1}\le 1$. Thus $b_1<1<b_{n+1}$

Define $c = (b_1 b_{n+1} )b_2\cdots b_n$ so $(b_1 b_{n+1} )+b_2 \cdots +b_n >n$ using our inductive hypothesis. So $(b_{n+1}-1)(1-b_1)=b_{n+1}-b_{n+1}b_1+b_1-1>0$ and then

\begin{align}b_1+ \cdots +b_n +
b_{n+1}= b_1+ \cdots +b_n +
b_{n+1}-b_{n+1}b_1+b_{n+1}b_1-1+1\\
=(b_{n+1}-1)(1-b_1)+(b_2+\cdots +b_n)+b_{n+1}b_1+1\\
>(b_2+\cdots +b_n)+b_{n+1}b_1+1 \\
>n+1\end{align}

as was to be shown. $\square$

**Proposition**: If $x_i >0$ for all $i$. Then
$(x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n}$ $<$ $(x_1+...x_n)\over n$

Proof: We assume that $x_1< x_n$. Define $G=(x_1x_2\cdots x_n)^{1/n}>0$ and write $b_j=x_j/G$ for all $j\in \{1\cdots n\}$. Then $b_1\cdots b_n=1$, $b_j>0$ for all $j$ and $b_1<b_n$, i.e., not all $b_j$ are equal. Then by the above lemma we may have

$$b_1+\cdots +b_n=\frac{x_1+\cdots x_n}{G}>n$$
$$G=(x_1 x_2 ... x_n)^{1/n}<\frac{x_1+\cdots x_n}{n} $$

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Take log on both sides and apply Jensen since log is concave.
Induction definitely works if you are doing it correctly. A easier way is to show for n = 2^k and use backward induction.

Comment: I believe backward induction is called "Fermat's principle of finite descent" or something like that.

Comment: I don't remember clearly but that seems to be a technique to show there are no integer solution to some algebraic equations.

Comment: You're right. [I stand corrected](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath288.htm)

Comment: Apparently it's also called Cauchy induction https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Cauchy_Induction

Answer (score 0):

Quick proof: take log both sides, and consider f(x) = lnx, then f''(x) = -1/x^2 < 0. Then use Jensen's inequality to get the answer.